# Async Message Testing

Tags: testing, asynchronous, automation, queue

Here is the problem I am facing with respect to Asynchronous Testing.  The Problem statement is as below

I get a big batch of xml with data of multiple candidates.  We do some validations and split that big xml into multiple xml's for each candidate. Each and every xml is persisted to the file structured database wih a Unique Identifier. A Unique identifier is generated for each of the messages that got persisted to the database. Each of those unique identifier's are hosted on to the Queue for subscription.

I am working on developing the automation test framework.  I am looking for a way to let the test class know that unique idenifier has been subscribed by the next step in Data processing.

I have read information regarding the above problem. Most of which specifies Thread sleeps and timers. The problem what would happen is when we run the large number of test cases, it takes enoromously large amount of time.

Have read Awaitility. Had some hopes on it. Any ideas and anyonehas faced a similar situation. Please help.

Thanks
DevAutotester

Answer (score 0):

You could use Awaitility to wait until all id's exists in the db or queue (if I understand it correctly) and then continue to do the validation afterwards. You will have to provide a supplier to Awaitility that checks that all IDs are present. Awaitility will then wait for this statement to be true.

/Johan

Comment: Will the awaitility keeps the Thread sleep for a stipulated amount of time or is it having flexibility to immediately start as soon as the wait statement becomes True? The reason why I am asking is we might be having 100 +test cases to run, keeping the waits would screw up the test execution time. If the waiting stops as soon as it finds the statement is True then it helps. Could you please confirm?

Comment: It uses polling so it won't stop _exactly_ when the statement returns true. You can configure the poll interval and initial poll delay (see http://code.google.com/p/awaitility/wiki/Usage page). By the default the poll interval is 100 ms so if you're _really_ unlucky you may loose 100 ms for each test.